# Symfony2 Twig_Error_Loader - Twig doesn't find templates

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, twig

I look for a while, but don't find a solution. I have a Symfony2 project that I'm trying to deploy. The strcture that I have is this:

```
/www/my_app/ -> where lives all symfony folders (app, bin, src and vendor) but 'web'
/www/public_html/my_app/ -> this is the 'web' folder renamed to 'my_app'
```

With this structure I change the routes in app.php:

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../../my_app/app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../../my_app/app/AppKernel.php';
```

And I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Loader' with message 'The "D:\www\public_html\my_app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle/Resources/views" directory does not exist.' in D:\www\my_app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php on line 93
Twig_Error_Loader: The "D:\www\public_html\my_app\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle/Resources/views" directory does not exist. in D:\www\my_app\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Filesystem.php on line 93
```

The problems is that that files that Twig are trying to load no lives in "D:\www\public_html\my_app\vendor", but in "D:\www\my_app\vendor".

I hope that you can get the problem. I'm running the app within apache.

Thanks in advance for any comment.

Comment: It looks like the was to name both directories 'my_app'. I rename the directory in public_html to web_my_app and everything starts to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it would help in your case, but when I want to load twig templates from other directories in controller I run:

```
$this->get('twig.loader')->addPath('../app');
```

This is just example how I tell Twig - "I want also use templates from other ../app path".

Comment: Thanks, but this no looks that a solution for this. I don't have a special folder for templates, I simply split the structure of Symfony. And the templates that Twig doesn't find are there own.